# Как правильно вставить запись в NULL, а если нету то добавить строку

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть причина?
если нету NULL то тогда добавляем строку, если есть то изменяем NULL на значение

```html
IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) stolb FROM tabl WHERE stolb IS NULL) == 0) THEN
 INSERT INTO tabl (stolb) VALUES ('znach');
ELSE
 UPDATE tabl SET stolb='znach' WHERE stolb IS NULL LIMIT 1;
END IF;
```

Сделал так

```html
SET @A = (SELECT id FROM tabl WHERE stolb IS NULL LIMIT 1);
INSERT INTO tabl (id,stolb) VALUES (@A,znach)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE stolb = VALUES(stolb);
```

Comment: IF нельзя использовать в SQL запросах, ибо он не относится к языку SQL вообще. Его можно использовать только в хранимых процедурах. А вам нужен INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Comment: С имеющими значениями разобрался, но мне нужно вносить где содержится NULL ? если нету, то новую строку. Как реализовать правильно?